# Rails admin import fails with belongs to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, admin, rails-admin

I'm using rails 6, rails admin and rails_admin_import

I want to import some data via CVS to my app, this is my Model:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
end

class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and this is an example of my CVS file Structure:

```
Name;Phone;list_id
Ali Cate;+573133333333;1
Alan Brito;+5733333333;1
```

but When I import the file I have this result:

```
Failed to create : List must exist
Failed to create : List must exist
```

I've tryed with diferents headers for my CVS file, but I had the same result:

```
Name;Phone;list
Name;Phone;list id
Name;Phone;id
```

**EDIT:**

I found my problem, I need to use , not ; in my CVS file....

but with that change I get this issue:

> Error during import: List(#70256226968860) expected, got # which is an instance of
>   List(#70256206360100)
>   (.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:287:in
>   `raise_on_type_mismatch!')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution Here: https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import/issues/88

I only needed to restart the server